# Try catch array value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

i have an array and i want to get the value this array with jquery. but i dont know how to get this array. Here's my code

exam.php

```
<?php
   $a = array(0=>'Black',1=>'Yellow');
?>
```

form.html

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
<input type hidden name="var1" id="var1" value="<?=$a;?>">
</form>
```

and this for jquery script

```
var x = $("#var1").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse it,

```
var x = JSON.parse($("#var1").val());
```

It will convert the array string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have used jQuery, if the jQuery version is appropriate, you can also use:

```
$.parseJSON(your_json_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't `echo` an array in PHP. You need to convert it into a string that JavaScript can parse. JSON. Use `echo json_encode($a);` to do that.

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="var1" 
       id="var1" 
       value='<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>'>
```

Next, to get the value in jQuery. You need to call `JSON.parse` to convert it into a JavaScript Object.

```
var val = $('#var1').val();
val = JSON.parse(val);
// ["Black", "Yellow"]
```